# Run an android emulator on a headless server

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, kvm, headless

I have a headless Debian server that I used to use for CI and testing. I don't know what happened but it broke, so I removed the whole SDK and started from scratch.

I did:

- Retrieve the latest URL with:

  ```
  curl -s 'https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads' \
      | grep -oP 'https?://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux[^" ]+' \
      | sort | uniq
  ```
- downloaded it & unzipped it
- updated the SDK manager:

  ```
   ./tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
  ```
- accepted the licenses:

  ```
   yes | ./tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  ```
- installed everything for API level 27:

  ```
  ./tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-27" "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
  ```
- I have installed KVM and Qemu according to the instructions
- I have created an AVD with:

  ```
  echo no | ./tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name avdname -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
  ```
- then started the emulator:

  ```
  ./emulator/emulator @avdname -no-window
  ```

It starts but in logcat it complains about the lack of Qemu:

```
01-09 23:15:19.278  4075  4075 D libEGL  : Emulator has vendor provided software renderer, qemu.gles is set to 2.
01-09 23:15:19.282  4075  4075 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-09 23:15:19.283  4075  4075 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-09 23:15:19.288  4075  4075 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-09 23:15:19.294  4075  4075 E         : connect: failed with fd -1 errno 22
01-09 23:15:19.294  4075  4075 E         : Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
01-09 23:15:19.294  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: Failed to establish connection with the host
01-09 23:15:19.294  4075  4075 W libEGL  : eglInitialize(0xab2fb014) failed (EGL_SUCCESS)
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 I /system/bin/surfaceflinger: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglGetConfigs(774): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglChooseConfig(796): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglGetConfigs(774): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglChooseConfig(796): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.295  4075  4075 W SurfaceFlinger: no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
01-09 23:15:19.296  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglGetConfigs(774): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.296  4075  4075 E EGL_emulation: tid 4075: eglChooseConfig(796): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
01-09 23:15:19.296  4075  4075 F SurfaceFlinger: no suitable EGLConfig found, giving up
01-09 23:15:19.296  4075  4075 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4075 (surfaceflinger), pid 4075 (surfaceflinger)
01-09 23:15:19.305  4086  4086 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
01-09 23:15:19.306  1592  1592 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 4075
01-09 23:15:19.307  4086  4086 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 4075 (target tid = 4075)
```

I have `hw.gpu.enabled = false`, not sure if it is relevant.

KVM is happy:

```
$ ./tools/emulator -accel-check
accel:
0
KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
accel
```

I don't know if KVM is the issue or if the GPU acceleration is something else.

Interestingly, this works like a charm:

```
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64" "platforms;android-26"
echo no | ./tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name avd26 -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64"
./emulator/emulator @avd26 -no-window
```

Is it because it's an x86_64 image? Because the API 27 system image is buggy? Why isn't there a 64 bit image for API 27 b the way?

Answer (score 1):

try running the emulator with these params in addition to the `-no-window` param:

`qemu -enable-kvm -snapshot`

I had similar issues starting the emulators recently in a headless environment and this helped me resolve it. System image version should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-gpu swiftshader`. This seems to fix the issue for me.